# Theoretically: If I released a giant cloud of Oxygen into space, would you be able to hear sound inside of it before it dissipated?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, acoustics, vacuum, estimation

If I released a giant cloud of Oxygen into space, would you be able to hear sound inside of it before it dissipated?

From my understanding, the reason there is no sound in space is because there are no atoms for the sounds waves to interact with. So if you theoretically put atoms in space would they carry the sound?

Comment: This may answer your question https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/pia16881-sounds-of-the-ancient-universe

Answer (score 3):

Audio-frequency sound doesn’t travel in space because the wavelength of the sound waves is longer than the mean free path of the residual gas molecules in the vacuum. This isn’t an issue in air at standard pressure, where the mean free path is typically about 70 nm, while sound wavelengths are macroscopic. But in space, where a typical number density is a few atoms per cubic centimeter, the mean free paths are macroscopic.

The speed of sound is closely related to the typical speed of gas molecules due to thermal motion. (That’s why the speed of sound varies like the square root of the absolute temperature, because $\frac12 m\left<v^2\right>\propto kT$.) If you were to take something like an oxygen cylinder into space and let it burst, the oxygen molecules would flee into the vacuum at roughly the speed of sound. So sound from the dense part of the cloud couldn’t “catch up” with the part that’s fleeing into the vacuum. You could ask whether acoustic density modulations in the bulk of the gas might be transmitted into density modulations in the escaping gas, allowing transient sound transmission or sound transmission by pointing a narrow stream of escaping gas at some sensor. But that feels contrary to the spirit of your question.

A gas cloud which is many orders of magnitude larger than its mean free path can support acoustic oscillations again, but not corresponding to human-audible wavelengths.  The Sun’s photosphere is a pretty good vacuum by Earth standards, but supports oscillations enough to study helioseismology. The literature  discusses the role of shock waves (an acoustic phenomenon) in the collapse of cold gas clouds, as well as the arms of spiral galaxies as density waves which propagate through the interstellar medium. Another search term is “baryon acoustic oscillations.”